# Converting Timestamp from chr to Time/Data-Type in R

Tags: r, datetime, time, type-conversion

I started working with R and I have a small problem with Timestamps.
I am cleaning my Data for a case study and I don't like to see the Timestamps classified as a chr Datatype.

```
$ time         <chr> "00:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00…
```

I want to convert them to an adequate data type.
I am first of all confused about the right data type for this information.
I saw people converting them into a date, which does not seem right to me?

I tried different strategies that I saw online but I was just not successful.
There must be an easy way to convert this data to another data type.

If someone could help me, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These could be represented as chron `"times"` objects (which are internally represented as a fraction of a day) or lubridate `"Period"` S4 objects.  Externally they are rendered as shown.

```
ch <- c("00:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:00:00", "03:00:00")

library(chron)
times(ch)
## [1] 00:00:00 01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00
 
library(lubridate)
hms(ch)
## [1] "0S"       "1H 0M 0S" "2H 0M 0S" "3H 0M 0S"
```

Comment: llubridate::hour(hms(ch)) or chron::hours(times(ch)) will extract the hour.  Be careful since both packages have hours functions.  chron times can handle NA's.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used the chron package - times and it worked perfectly. Thanks!